# How to convert a Blogger XML file to a WXR file?

Tags: xml, wordpress, blogger, file-conversion

I have a Blogger export file that is 47.9MB that I need to import into WordPress (self-hosted). Normally, I use the Google App tool to convert those files, then split them up into smaller bits for import into WP.

However, I keep getting this error:

> 413 Error: Request Entity Too Large  Your client issued a request that
>   was too large.

Is there another app I can use for such a large file or some tutorial on how to convert an XML file manually to a WXR file?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I'm really struggling with this exact issue right now...

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to do this at all - according to the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Blogger), you can import from blogger directly

The pertinent bit from the link above says:

> Users of WordPress 2.2 and above can import from Blogger. Earlier
>   versions cannot import from Blogger because "New Blogger" was released
>   by Google, invalidating all the old importers. Only WordPress 2.2 and
>   later has support for "New Blogger".
>
> If you haven't already, you must be using New Blogger and a Google
>   Account on Blogger. If you are still using Old Blogger, the importer
>   will not work, but there is a helpful online tool  that converts
>   legacy Blogger Atom exports into Wordpress WXR export files.
>
> To start the Blogger importer, go to Tools → Import → Blogger. For
>   WordPress versions 2.0.2 to 2.6.5, go to Manage → Import → Blogger.

Comment: Yes, I do need to convert the file. The WordPress import tool does not always bring over all posts/images. This is the surefire way to get everything at once.